# Algebra of Sets: Proof of absorption laws without using DeMorgan's laws?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove set algebras's absoption laws **without using DeMorgan's laws**.

Absoption laws :

1. $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$
2. $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$

Is this possible?

I would like to prove these laws **using only set algebra's laws , without analysing the sentences set theoretically in terms of membership relation.**

I can prove , for example, that  $A \cup ( A \cap B)$ is included in $A$ , by proving that

$( A \cup (A \cap B)) \cap A^\complement = \emptyset$

( here I use the fact that : $X \subseteq Y \iff X \cap Y^\complement= \emptyset$).

But the reverse inclusion, applying the same strategy, would require me to use De Morgan's laws).

Following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra) I take

(1) As axioms & definitions

- commutativity of U and Inter
- associativity of U and Inter
- distributivity of U over Inter , and reciprocally
- identity laws
- complement laws
- duality law
- definition of inclusion
- definition of equality ( as reciprocal inclusion)

(2) As derived laws ( provable using axioms and definitions)

- idempotent laws for U and Inter  ( Which I managed to prove)
- domination laws          ( Which I managed to prove)
- absoption laws      ( Here, I am stuck)
- DeMorgan's laws     ( Here, also stuck)
- etc.

Comment: The "axioms" say almost nothing on complements so it's no wonder you cannot show de Morgan, I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. I first would like to prove absoption laws, in order to go from more basic to less basic, as if I were constructing a deductive system.

Answer (score 2):

$A \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq A$ follows from $A \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B \subseteq A$ right away, doesn't it? (interpreting $\cap$ as $\land$ (the infimum in a lattice) and $\cup, \lor$ as the supremum in a lattice )

It might be clearer if you state what "laws" you consider as "axioms" exactly.
The absorption law holds in any lattice, as I just sketched. This is basically from the definitions of sup and inf.

Trying to use your linked axioms:
$A \cup (A \cap B)$ by distributivity equals $(A \cup A) \cap (A \cup B)$ and by idempotency (proved on [your page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra) from your axioms) this equals $A \cap (A \cup B)$ which equals by distributivity again : $(A \cap A) \cup (A \cap B)$ and we're back at $A \cup (A \cap B)$ again. The linked page does not give a definition of inclusion really, but some equivalent statements for $A \subseteq B$, that I think do not derive from these axioms but from simple "element considerations".

Comment: Henno Brandsma.- I've edited my question to clarify which propositions I would like as primitive, and which ones as derived laws.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames what Wikipedia page? You can include links...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma.Sorry  I forgot to include the  link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra